# How can I change the A record for my DNS while redirecting users from old IP to the new IP?

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, http

I have a DNS record that points to ipA (A record). I want to change the record to ipB, however I cannot accept anything on ipA as soon as ipB is in use, because the application can't exist in two different places.

The application works on HTTP protocol. What are my options to redirect users going to ipA, considering I don't have root access but I have access to the NGINX configuration?

Comment: What is an acceptable downtime duration for this service? Do you manage the devices of your users?

Comment: @JohnMahowald I don't manage the devices. An acceptable downtime is up to 48 hours (I'd love it to be 24 hours though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a client requests the IP address for a DNS name, the response is cached by both the resolving DNS server and the client.  The default TTL (number of seconds to cache the response) is usually 12-24 hours.  This can be temporarily changed to make a migration smoother.

Easy option - Reduce your TTL on your DNS(s) record down to something like 300 (5 minutes) at least 24-48 hours before you migrate your app, so that clients should only cache the IP address for your DNS name for a short time.  Any client that resolves your DNS name after you change the IP address will continue to be directed to the old IP address for as long as the old IP address is cached, but then once it's expired they'll resolve it to the new IP address.  There will be a few minutes of downtime for clients with the old IP address in their cache.

Another option would be to create an additional A record for your application with a different name, which would resolve to the new IP address straight away, then setup a temporary redirect in your NGINX configuration on the old server.

I'm not familiar with NGINX, but Google found some instructions that might help here: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/redirecting-urls-using-nginx/

1. User wants to go to app.somedomain.com, but their computer has the old IP address in their DNS cache or the resolving DNS server has it in its cache
2. Their HTTP request goes to your old server, which redirects them to your temporary domain name app2.somedomain.com, resolves to your new IP address and a new HTTP request is sent to your new server.
3. Once the old record expires in their DNS cache, future requests will resolve to the new IP address and they'll go straight to the new server